# Change SVN working directory to own repository

Tags: svn

So I have checked out a repository of an online project with `svn checkout <url>`. However, I obviously can't commit to it, since it's not mine. How do I convert that working copy to my own, local repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subversion isn't DVCS (like git) so you can't do it what do you want (commit locally and push to repository). More about it check [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.intro.whatis.html#svn.intro.righttool).

But if you want "fork" the repository you can do it. You can use [`svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnrdump.html) which dumps a remote repository. You can use this dump to create own repository and should checkout this with [`svnadmin load`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html).

```
# dump the remote repository
svnrdump dump URL > dumpfile
# create an empty repository
svnadmin create /own/repository/path
# load the dumpfile into own repository
svnadmin load /own/repository/path < dumpfile
# checkout your locally repository
svn checkout /own/repository/path /your/checkout/dir
```

Now you can commit changes and create diffs to send it as patch to the original repository.